# IOS Splash Screen renders correctly then elements jump to top

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, splash-screen, xcode-storyboard

So I have the following Splash Screen:

[image]

Which loads up normally but then jumps to the following:

[image]

My constraints are the following :S So I think I have my elements properly constrained and also when checking the different devices in xcode everything looks okay. But as soon as the app starts it initally loads correctly but before loading the next view everything jumps to the top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
<device id="retina3_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16086"/>
    <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Ydg-fD-yQy"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="xbc-2k-c8Z"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <imageView opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleAspectFill" image="LaunchImage" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="YRO-k0-Ey4">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="480"/>
                        </imageView>
                        <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="growthdecks_logo_white" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="oIG-AW-V5d">
                            <rect key="frame" x="38" y="110" width="245" height="260.5"/>
                        </imageView>
                        <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="millesanders_logo_white" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RMx-ME-VmL">
                            <rect key="frame" x="103" y="398" width="115" height="82"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="82" id="rA5-25-iAt"/>
                            </constraints>
                        </imageView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="RMx-ME-VmL" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="87" id="40k-Ob-jLK"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="oIG-AW-V5d" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="21" id="8zN-eu-A0s"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="YRO-k0-Ey4" secondAttribute="trailing" id="CfB-dj-2FI"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="RMx-ME-VmL" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="86" id="D7Z-vK-LvD"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="YRO-k0-Ey4" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="leading" id="Heg-3Y-CWr"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="oIG-AW-V5d" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="22" id="QGg-5c-RsU"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="YRO-k0-Ey4" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="top" id="ZYU-cd-jlT"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="oIG-AW-V5d" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Ydg-fD-yQy" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="110" id="nP2-0E-Opq"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="xbc-2k-c8Z" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="RMx-ME-VmL" secondAttribute="bottom" id="qQf-sf-irV"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="YRO-k0-Ey4" secondAttribute="bottom" id="uzq-64-XwI"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="75.362318840579718" y="250.44642857142856"/>
    </scene>
</scenes>
<resources>
    <image name="LaunchImage" width="2344.5" height="5075"/>
    <image name="growthdecks_logo_white" width="261" height="260.5"/>
    <image name="millesanders_logo_white" width="1152.5" height="260.5"/>
</resources>
```

I am using flutter but I think this is a native ios issue :S 
This is what it looks like in xcode

[image]

Comment: When things appear in the wrong place, it usually mean you have _insufficient constraints_. In this instance, what would determine the height / bottom of the `growthdecks_logo_white` image view? And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was constraining my logos to the layout instead of the superview along the vertical axis. :S That did the trick for me

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by this? I have a similar issue and am not able to understand your fix based on that sentence alone? How did you rectify this constraint issue - xCode is _really_ difficult to use for these things if you're not used to it.

Comment: @HBG well it was quite specific and I also don't have that code anymore ;D If you send me a screenshot I can take a look though :) (or GitHub repo or some way to look at the constraints)

Comment: Yeah this answer says nothing. What's the superview here?

Answer (score 5):

Check that your constraints are referencing the Superview rather than the Layout:

1. Click on the specific constraint in the list to the left of the preview
2. In the Inspector to the right of the preview (select menu View -> Inspectors -> Show Inspector if it's not visible) show the Attributes Inspector by clicking the three sliders icon.
3. Look at the First Item and Second Item entry. If either of them references Layout, click the menu and select Superview instead.
4. Repeat for the remaining constraints. Save and build.

Comment: I spent hours on hours on this, thanks! It worked. This should have been the excepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set image as a aspect fit from launch.storyboard